# Decision Making using Multiple Variables

Tags: decision-problem

What should I learn if I want to make a decision based on multiple variables? Followings are the example of a problem.

I have a farm. My variables are weather, humidity of air, humidity of soil, size of my fruits, etc.. Every hour, I will capture every data and store it in my database. My possible decisions are "Harvest", "Plant", "Wait". Sorry if this question is too generalized or too broad. I do not know what I want to learn.

Comment: It sounds like a control problem with continuous state space. You might want to look into Reinforcement Learning.

Comment: @ShahafFinder thank you for the recommendation. I have read some text regarding on my problem. Turns out there are no ways (yet?) to solve my issue since it is dealing with uncertainties and white noises.

Comment: If so, it will be interesting to see how well can you approximate it. If it interests you, don't give up :) Maybe try solving an easier problem first (say, a simulated problem with no noise).

Comment: @ShahafFinder but how can one make a decision if they do not even know that they do not have enough variable or not (hence the white noise).. to be honest, I think my research is stalling because I don't think I have enough variables to include in my statistics, but I just dont know what it is or how to find it. I feel so defeated.

Comment: Maybe you can ask in Cross Validated, they might have a better idea of these kind of stuff. https://stats.stackexchange.com/